# How do I call the default deserializer in a custom deserializer in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON object that has 3 different objects in use.

```
{ // Class A
"name" : "Name",
"list" : { 
    "names" : { //Class B
        "scale1" : { //Class C
            "max" : 10,
            "min" : 0
        },
        "scale2" : { //Class C
            "max" : 20,
            "min" : 15
        }
    }
} }
```

Class A contains a Map< String,Class B>, and Class B contains a Map< String,Class C>.  The issue I am having is that I have a custom deserializer for class B but I want to use the default deserializer for class C.

I want to have it something like this:

```
public class BDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<B> {
@Override
public B deserialize(JsonParser arg0, DeserializationContext arg1)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    B bObject = new B();
    while(!arg0.isClosed()){            
        C cObject = CDeserializer.deserialize()
        bObject.names.add(cObject);     
    }
    return bObject;
} }
```

But I am not sure what arguments to pass into the CDeserializer, or if there is a away for me to call a default deserializer for class C.

The classes look roughly like:

```
public class A {
String name;
Map<String,B> list = new HashMap<String,B>();

//getters & setters

}
public class B {
String name;
Map<String,C> fields = new HashMap<String,C>();

//getters & setters

}

public class C {
String name;
long min;
long max;

//getters & setters

}
```

Comment: Could you also show your POJO classes for above JSON?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `JsonParser` object to read all properties. See below example:

```
class BJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<B> {

    @Override
    public B deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        B result = new B();
        result.setFields(new HashMap<String, C>());

        while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            String name = parser.getCurrentName();
            if ("scale1".equals(name) || "scale2".equals(name) || "anotherProperty".equals(name)) {
                parser.nextToken();
                result.getFields().put(name, parser.readValueAs(C.class));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

- [Jackson JSON Processing API in Java Example Tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial).

Comment: That's not really answering the question, is it?
As you don't show how to call the standard deserialiser.

Comment: 'parser.readValueAs(C.class)' - invokes standard deserializer. You have to move parser into right point and invoke 'readValueAs' method with class you expects it's there.

Comment: yeah, that works when you know what class to expect there. But what if you want to build something more generic

Comment: @RaduSimionescu, you have to specify what do you mean by "generic"?

Comment: well, you know who B is and you manually populate its fields on deserialization. A generic deserializer would be able to deserialize ANYTHING, just given the class of the desired output instance. You may have worked out a sollution for one class, but you didn't answer the question. How to call the default deserializer... which would be needed if those fields were complex

Comment: I've got your point. But the key point of my answer is `parser.readValueAs(C.class)`. It invokes default deserializer for `C` class. To write generic solution you have to write complex Reflection related code which would hide real value of my answer. I agree with you, my answer could be better and much generic but it takes a time to write answer like you proposed. So, I've gave just and idea without solid implementation.